# Retrieving Custom Document Metadata from SharePoint using Microsoft Graph

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am trying to retrieve custom document metadata using the Microsoft Graph API but when I specify the name of the facets used the data is not returned.

`var items = graph.Drives[drive.Id].Search(q).Request().Top(num_results).Select("id,name,file,weburl,createdby,lastmodifiedby,createddatetime,lastmodifieddatetime,package,revision").GetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

The above facets used are returning the data except for package and revision, which are unique to my sharepoint instance.

Is there any way to return the data for these columns/facets when I do a search using the Microsoft Graph API?

Answer (score 3):

You can access these fields by treating the library as a `list` instead of a `drive` - instead of calling `/v1.0/sites/FOO/drives/BAR/children`, you call `/v1.0/sites/FOO/lists/BAZ/items?expand=fields`.

Given a drive ID, you can request `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/DRIVE_ID/list` to get the list.

Comment: This should be marked as the solution. I got all metadata, including Taxonomy data.

Answer (score 1):

For custom document metadata on a specific document use the Get *list* item method where the item-id refers to the specific document in the list like this:  v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}
Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-get

The item-id is the id to the specific document returned by GET list items method on lists documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

This returns any custom medata fields

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following API to get labels and metadata, by by on my test, it won't return the custom metadata now:

```
By the driveItem unique identifier using drive/items/{item-id}
By file system path using /drive/root:/path/to/file

GET /drives/{drive-id}/root/search(q='{search-text}')
GET /groups/{group-id}/drive/root/search(q='{search-text}')
GET /me/drive/root/search(q='{search-text}')
GET /sites/{site-id}/drive/root/search(q='{search-text}')
GET /users/{user-id}/drive/root/search(q='{search-text}')
```

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_search
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/driveitem

If you cannot get the information by the expand=fields too, I'd suggest you to submit a feature request: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

Comment: I am unable to get the information through one query / the search query itself but by selecting the SharePoint list information that the search document is apart of I was able to get the list and list item ID. These were then used to make a separate call to graph to retrieve the missing document properties.

Comment: Many custom metadata cannot be obtained from the above api, so if it doesn't work, just submit the feature request or change your project design.